# missing attributes name in rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have the following query in my rails app but its result does not have attributes name so I am not able to use it in amcharts

```
EmployeeDepartment.joins(:states).group
("employee_departments.name").count
```

the result is : `{"Academic Support":1}`

how to make it like this `{"department_name":"Academic Support","department_count":1}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by this steps:

the following code:

```
 EmployeeDepartment.joins(:states).group
    ("employee_departments.name").count
```

generates this in `rails console`

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, employee_departments.name AS employee_departments_name FROM "employee_departments" INNER JOIN "tickets" ON "tickets"."employee_department_id" = "employee_departments"."id" INNER JOIN "states" ON "states"."id" = "tickets"."state_id" GROUP BY employee_departments.name
```

i used what was generated in the `console` in the following:

```
@department_count = EmployeeDepartment.find(:all,
            :select => 'employee_departments.name AS employee_departments_name, COUNT(*) AS department_counter',
            :joins => 'INNER JOIN tickets ON tickets.employee_department_id = employee_departments.id INNER JOIN states ON states.id = tickets.state_id',
            :group => 'employee_departments.name')
```

Now the result in amcharts is:

```
var chartData = [{"department_counter":1,"employee_departments_name":"Academic Support"}];
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a hash like this:

```
hash = { "Academic Support" => 1, "Another Department" => 3, "Something Else" => 4 }
```

You can just use `map` to transform it into an array of hashes containing what you need.

```
hash.map { |k, v| { "department_name" => k, "department_count" => v } }
=> [{"department_name"=>"Academic Support", "department_count"=>1}, 
    {"department_name"=>"Another Department", "department_count"=>3}, 
    {"department_name"=>"Something Else", "department_count"=>4}]
```

If your hash only ever contains one key/value pair and you just want another hash, you could try this:

```
 Hash[[["department_name", "department_count"], hash.first].transpose]
```

Or even simpler...

```
 { "department_name" => hash.keys.first, "department_count" => hash.values.first }
```